# How to sort a Linked List based in one word of the String java

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, iterator, insertion-sort

I want to Sort a Linked List, I have watched so many  tutorials videos and examples, and I know how to sort a Linked List, but only Linked Lists with a single String, my Linked List is composed by sentences and I have to sort using one word in the sentences for example.

this list (Number Two: 2), (Number three : 3), (Number one : 1) like this (Number one: 1), (Number Two: 2), (Number three : 3)

I tried to split my linked list and use an iterator but I don't know what to do after.please help.

```
private LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

list.add("Number three : 3");
list.add("Number One : 1");
list.add("Number two : 2");

for(Iterator<String> iterator =list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) 
                {
                    String string = iterator.next();
                   for (String word : string.split(" ")){

                     /* if (int.TryParse(word)){ Maybe to get the number?


                      }*/

                   }


            }
```

15 hours  trying to figure out this, so any idea is welcome :).

Comment: why don't you use `Collections.sort(list);`

Answer (score 3):

There are probably a few ways to this, but you could write a custom `Comparator` which calculates the difference between the two values passed to it in the manner you want...

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

list.add("Number three : 3");
list.add("Number three : 1");
list.add("Number three : 2");

System.out.println("Not sorted...");
for (String value : list) {
    System.out.println(value);
}

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        String w1 = getWordFrom(o1);
        String w2 = getWordFrom(o2);
        return w1.compareTo(w2);
    }

    protected String getWordFrom(String value) {

        String[] parts = value.split(":");
        return parts[1].trim();

    }
});

System.out.println("Now sorted...");
for (String value : list) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Will output

```
Not sorted...
Number three : 3
Number three : 1
Number three : 2
Now sorted...
Number three : 1
Number three : 2
Number three : 3
```

Now, this is a very simple example and doesn't have a condition for a `String` missing the delimiter, but I guess you get the idea...

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code :**

```
public class SortList {
    private static LinkedList<String> list= new LinkedList<String>();
    public static void main(String s[]) {

        list.add("Number three : 3");
        list.add("Number three : 1");
        list.add("Number three : 2");

        System.out.println("list :"+list);
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println("sorted list :"+list);
    }
}
```

Comment: That only works if all the elements are the same except for the number. sorry my list.add codes were wrong I edited